# open an external link inside react js app under my navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to open an external link inside my react app under my navbar. I am using react router to navigate between pages. This is my code, I want when the user navigate to "/WebSite" it opens the website url under my navbar. Any help please !

```
 const App = ()=>{
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <NavBar/>
      <Route path="/Home" render={()=> <Home/>}/>
      <Route path='/SearchMagazine' render={()=> <SearchMagazine />}/>
      <Route path='/WebSite' component={() => <WebSite/>}/>
      <Route path="/Connection" render={()=> <Connection/>}/>
      <Route path="/FacebookPage" render={()=> <FacebookPage/>}/>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
 }
```

Comment: Never tried it but i believe you could use  Redirect of react router : <Route path=“/FacebookPage render={()=> <Redirect to=“https://www.facebook.com”/>}/>

Comment: You could create a `Route` with a component that has an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: iframe did all the work, thank you man !

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use:

```
<Route path='/WebSite' component={() => { window.location.replace('Any External Url'); return null;} }/>
```

Works both on React Router 3 and 4.

Comment: That doesn't fulfil the requirement in the question: "it opens the website url **under my navbar**"

Comment: Re edit: That just breaks the Back button. It doesn't fix the problem I pointed out in my previous comment.